# Excel report which rolls-up task work item attributes original estimate, completed, and remaining work hours to a parent requirement work item

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

In TFS when I setup a new iteration, I start out by creating "Requirement" work items, which are then associated with multiple child "Task" work items.  On the task work items I put the estimate for the task and then as the task is worked on the completed and remaining hours are updated.

What I want is an excel report that will show a breakdown of iteration, requirements, and task, with the hours totaled at the requirement and iteration level.

I envision this to be some kind of pivot table but I can't figure out how to pull in the data so I can relate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no rollup available out of the box in TFS 2010. You could write a macro in Excel to calculate the rollup hours and pivot on that.

You could also use the SSRS report User Story Overview to see the value, but that value is delayed (which is probably not what you want).

You could also take a look at the [Project Server Integration CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=f221c660-161b-43ca-95f3-e0e4aad8d43e), which has the rollup feature.

Answer (score 0):

If instead of Excel, you use an Agile planning web application for TFS such as [Urban Turtle](http://urbanturtle.com), you will obtain rollup feature at the requirement and iteration level.

According to Microsoft, the premier Agile tooling for TFS is Urban Turtle. Discloser: I work with the Urban Turtle team. So do not take my words. Instead, read what Brian Harry, who is the Product Unit Manager for Team Foundation Server, said about Urban Turtle: "...awesome Scrum experience for TFS." You can read Brian Harry's blog [here](http://urbanturtle.com/awesome)